# Linaro toolchain for windows with softfp

Tags: windows, arm, linaro

Not exactly programming/code related, but related to Linaro compiler utilities toolchain.

I am trying to find a Linaro toolchain for Windows platform for armv7-a architecture, but which is compiled/configured with a soft floating point abi i.e.  `--with-float=soft`
I have searched [here](https://launchpad.net/linaro-toolchain-binaries/+download) but there is none which i am looking for.

If there isn't any I would try to build one. Towards that, would appreciate pointers about how to build a linaro toolchain.

What are steps involved  in building the linaro toolchain either on Ubuntu Linux or on a Windows under cygwin?

Answer (score 1):

If you go further back (to 12.04) you can find the older, non-hf versions.  The instructions to build them are in the README.txt.  The README.txt, source and crosstool package are in the same place.  You use an Ubuntu machine to build the Windows-hosted tools.